# Getting half data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a little problem I have a radtextbox with multiline rows, the issue is when I fill in all the

radtextbox and saving it to the DataBase after that I'm trying to Get all the data that I entered but I get only half of the stuff that I wrote in that radtext box

```
  <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtEditNotes" runat="server" Height="45px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="250px" MaxLength="100" TabIndex="21">
                                  </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

any idea??

Comment: Is the data being truncated when it's saved to the database?  When you step through in a debugger, at what specific point does the data get lost?

Comment: Anything to post to help us to help you? (maybe  some code? :) )

Comment: yes the data is truncated when its saved to the database. I went through the code and its saved properly but when I'm trying to get it back I'm getting half of the data

Comment: What does the database table definition look like?  What database are you using?

Comment: Notes  varchar(50) allow nulls=true  and the in the sp inorder to get the data ISNULL(P.Notes,'') AS 'Notes'

Comment: @user3002885 [*Imagine You're Trying To Answer The Question*](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your table definition in the database:

`Notes varchar(2000) allow nulls=true`

`varchar(max)` might also be worth considering if you're likely to have people writing a LOT of text in the text box.